# Method is executed but not has effect

Tags: c#, class, object, logic

I'm creating a class for manipulate XML, I created overload of my method RemoveNode

```
public partial class HWXml
{
    public string XmlFile;
    private XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    public HWXml(string XmlFile)
    {
        this.XmlFile = XmlFile;
    }

    public XmlNode SelectSingleNode(string NodePath)
    {
        XmlDoc.Load(XmlFile);
        return XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(NodePath);
    }

    public void RemoveNode(XmlNode removeChild)
    {
        XmlDoc.Load(XmlFile);
        removeChild.ParentNode.RemoveChild(removeChild);
        XmlDoc.Save(XmlFile);
    }

    public void RemoveNode(string RemoveChild)
    {
        XmlDoc.Load(XmlFile);
        XmlNode removeChild = XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(RemoveChild);
        removeChild.ParentNode.RemoveChild(removeChild);
        XmlDoc.Save(XmlFile);
    }
}
```

When I try remove node using string parameter, it works

```
private void RemoveXML_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyXmlClass myXmlClass = new MyXmlClass(XmlFile);
    myXmlClass.RemoveNode("root/Content");
}
```

But when I try remove node using XmlNode parameters, it will compile, execute, no error message, but no effect, it no remove nothing in the XML file.

```
private void RemoveXML_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyXmlClass myXmlClass = new MyXmlClass(XmlFile);
    XmlNode node = myXmlClass.SelectSingleNode("root/Conteudo");
    myXmlClass.RemoveNode(node);
}
```

What is problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`XmlNode` parameter is definitely not part of `XmlDoc` which you are loading inside this method (because you have this node before document is loaded). Thus manipulations on this node do not affect document which node does not belong to.

In second case you are selecting node of document which was loaded. This node belongs to xml tree which was just loaded into `XmlDoc`, thus removing node affects document.

What you should understand is how `XmlDocument` (same for `XDocument`) is loaded:

1. If it has some nodes (previously loaded) then all nodes are removed
2. `XmlReader` created
3. This reader reads input stream node by node
4. For each found node, new instance of appropriate class is created and added to document (e.g. if reader has read some element, then new `XmlElement` is created and added to current element of document)

So, you end up with graph of completely new objects which have no relation to objects which was created during previous load of xml. After loading xml, instance of `XmlDocument`  stays same, but it has completely new objects inside.